# Finding the row number of last row in column with a specific value in excel

Tags: excel

So I have a column with values, and I am looking for the highest/latest row number with a specific value.
An example:

[image]

In this case, I want a function that when searching for the last row number, within the value range, containing 0, it would return 8.

Another option is to get the index of the first empty cell and subtract 1.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Match gives the first, not last :-(

Answer (score 2):

To find row number of last 0 in a range you can use:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:A11=0),ROW(A1:A11))
```

Edit: To exclude empty cells from result:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/((A1:A11=0)*(A1:A11<>"")),ROW(A1:A11))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=MAX(IF(LookFor=LookIn,ROW(LookIn),0))
```

entered as an array formula CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER. `LookFor` is the value you're looking for, say 0, and `LookIn` is the range you're searching, say A1:A15.

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help. I entered =MAX(IF(0=E897:E908,ROW(E897:E908),0)) with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER but got #REF!. The values in the formula are correct, though.

Comment: Is that because cells E905 to E908 contain REF errors themselves?

Comment: Correct. You can handle the #REFs by nesting an IF(ISERROR(),,) in the formula.

Answer (score 0):

```
=MAX(IF(ISERROR(E897:E908),0,IF(E897:E908=0,ROW(E897:E908),0)))-ROW(E897)+1
```

CTRL+ENTER+SHIFT
I just checked if the line doesn't contain an error and if it doesn't, if it has my value I take the highest row number and then, from that, I subtract the initial row number, and get 8.